# Group by UUID with creating multiple columns for multiple entries of same UUID

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

So let's say I have a dataframe of this structure:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║             candidate_id             ║     public_id    ║ first_name ║ last_name ║        email       ║ phone_number ║     company_name     ║ years_of_experience ║        normalized_degree        ║                college_name                ║             specialization_path            ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ a132a4f9-fa42-4802-8958-228952240d47 ║ divyanshu-thakur ║  Divyanshu ║   Thakur  ║    xxx@gmail.com   ║     xxxx     ║        Google        ║          3          ║    Bachelor's / Undergraduate   ║ Indian Institute of Information Technology ║ Technical / Quantitative~>Computer Science ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 71cfc6b7-b601-4ca0-b894-0b9f48dad717 ║     kami-kms     ║    Kami    ║    Kms    ║  xxxxxx@yahoo.com  ║    xxxxxxx   ║        Groupon       ║          2          ║ High School Certificate/Diploma ║             Board of Education             ║    Technical / Quantitative~>Statistics    ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 71cfc6b7-b601-4ca0-b894-0b9f48dad717 ║     kami-kms     ║    Kami    ║    Kms    ║  xxxxxx@yahoo.com  ║    xxxxxxx   ║        Groupon       ║          2          ║    Bachelor's / Undergraduate   ║               ISBM University              ║    Technical / Quantitative~>Statistics    ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 8af6be9a-007e-4cfa-9965-aa65948e945f ║   kundan-mishra  ║   KUNDAN   ║   MISHRA  ║ xxxxxxxx@gmail.com ║   xxxxxxxx   ║       Mobikwik       ║          8          ║       Master's / Graduate       ║                     IIM                    ║       Business / Commerce~>Marketing       ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 8af6be9a-007e-4cfa-9965-aa65948e945f ║   kundan-mishra  ║   KUNDAN   ║   MISHRA  ║ xxxxxxxx@gmail.com ║    xxxxxxx   ║ OYO - Vacation Homes ║          8          ║       Master's / Graduate       ║                     IIM                    ║       Business / Commerce~>Marketing       ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I want to groupby all elements using `candidate_id` field.
So, what I want is:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════╗
║             candidate_id             ║     public_id    ║ first_name ║ last_name ║        email       ║ phone_number ║ company_1 ║ company_2            ║ years_of_experience ║        normalized_degree1       ║                college_name1               ║            specialization_path1            ║ normalized_degree2         ║ college_name2   ║ specialization_path2                 ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ a132a4f9-fa42-4802-8958-228952240d47 ║ divyanshu-thakur ║  Divyanshu ║   Thakur  ║    xxx@gmail.com   ║     xxxx     ║   Google  ║ NA                   ║          3          ║    Bachelor's / Undergraduate   ║ Indian Institute of Information Technology ║ Technical / Quantitative~>Computer Science ║ NA                         ║ NA              ║ NA                                   ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 71cfc6b7-b601-4ca0-b894-0b9f48dad717 ║     kami-kms     ║    Kami    ║    Kms    ║  xxxxxx@yahoo.com  ║    xxxxxxx   ║  Groupon  ║ NA                   ║          2          ║ High School Certificate/Diploma ║             Board of Education             ║    Technical / Quantitative~>Statistics    ║ Bachelor's / Undergraduate ║ ISBM University ║ Technical / Quantitative~>Statistics ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 8af6be9a-007e-4cfa-9965-aa65948e945f ║   kundan-mishra  ║   KUNDAN   ║   MISHRA  ║ xxxxxxxx@gmail.com ║   xxxxxxxx   ║  Mobikwik ║ OYO - Vacation Homes ║          8          ║       Master's / Graduate       ║                     IIM                    ║       Business / Commerce~>Marketing       ║ NA                         ║ NA              ║ NA                                   ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I am unable to find any way other than brute force to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sorting `MultiIndex in columns` by second level and flatten columns names by `f-string`s:

```
cols = ['candidate_id',' public_id','first_name','last_name',
        'email','phone_number','years_of_experience']

g = df.groupby(cols).cumcount().add(1)
df1 = df.set_index(cols + [g]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]}')
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: Is there any way that some entries won't go at the end even though it is only second entry for the current uuid. So what is happening that after using this code I am getting a lot of empty columns in between legit entries. I want the entries to be denser.

Comment: @Rajarshi - Unfortuantely it depends of data, pandas also add NaNs for not exist rows (if there is at least one row filled by data, all another rows are filled by NaNs)